# Google-Fit Sensors API Not Finding Watch

Tags: android, google-api, android-sensors, google-fit

I have implemented the Google Fit Sensors API in my project and it does not seem to be finding my watch when scanning for data sources

Here is my code for scanning for data sources

```
    private void findFitnessDataSources() {
        Log.i(TAG, "findFitnessDataSources called");
        // [START find_data_sources]
        // Note: Fitness.SensorsApi.findDataSources() requires the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission.
        Fitness.getSensorsClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this))
                .findDataSources(
                        new DataSourcesRequest.Builder()
                                .setDataTypes(DataType.TYPE_HEART_RATE_BPM)
                                .setDataSourceTypes(DataSource.TYPE_RAW)
                                .build())
                .addOnSuccessListener(
                        new OnSuccessListener<List<DataSource>>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(List<DataSource> dataSources) {
                                Log.i(TAG, "Listener Success");
                                Log.i(TAG, "DataSources: " + dataSources.size());
                                for (DataSource dataSource : dataSources) {
                                    Log.i(TAG, "Data source found: " + dataSource.toString());
                                    Log.i(TAG, "Data Source type: " + dataSource.getDataType().getName());

                                    // Let's register a listener to receive Activity data!
                                    if (dataSource.getDataType().equals(DataType.TYPE_HEART_RATE_BPM)
                                            && mListener == null) {
                                        Log.i(TAG, "Data source for HEART RATE found!  Registering.");
                                        registerFitnessDataListener(dataSource);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        })
                .addOnFailureListener(
                        new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                Log.e(TAG, "failed", e);
                            }
                        });
        // [END find_data_sources]
    }
```

The result is no data sources found. My watch had google fit updated and signed in on the same account as I select in the application. As far as I can tell it is successfully connecting to the API it is simply not reading any sensors to pull information out of. I am, of course, possibly wrong about that. If anyone can shed any light on this it would be much appreciated.

Below is all my code for this activity if it is relevant

```
    public class Test_Page extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView hR;
    public static final String TAG = "BasicSensorsApi";

    private static final int REQUEST_OAUTH_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    private static final int REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE = 34;

    // [START mListener_variable_reference]
    // Need to hold a reference to this listener, as it's passed into the "unregister"
    // method in order to stop all sensors from sending data to this listener.
    private OnDataPointListener mListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.test_page);

        hR = findViewById(R.id.heartRate);


        // When permissions are revoked the app is restarted so onCreate is sufficient to check for
        // permissions core to the Activity's functionality.
        if (hasRuntimePermissions()) {
            findFitnessDataSourcesWrapper();
        } else {
            requestRuntimePermissions();
        }
    }

    /**
     * A wrapper for {@link #findFitnessDataSources}. If the user account has OAuth permission,
     * continue to {@link #findFitnessDataSources}, else request OAuth permission for the account.
     */
    private void findFitnessDataSourcesWrapper() {
        Log.i(TAG, "findFitnessDataSourcesWrapper called");
        if (hasOAuthPermission()) {
            findFitnessDataSources();
        } else {
            requestOAuthPermission();
        }
    }

    /** Gets the {@link FitnessOptions} in order to check or request OAuth permission for the user. */
    private FitnessOptions getFitnessSignInOptions() {
        Log.i(TAG, "getFitnessSignInOptions calles");
        return FitnessOptions.builder().addDataType(DataType.TYPE_HEART_RATE_BPM, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_READ).build();
    }

    /** Checks if user's account has OAuth permission to Fitness API. */
    private boolean hasOAuthPermission() {
        Log.i(TAG, "hasOAuthPermission called");
        FitnessOptions fitnessOptions = getFitnessSignInOptions();
        return GoogleSignIn.hasPermissions(GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this), fitnessOptions);
    }

    /** Launches the Google SignIn activity to request OAuth permission for the user. */
    private void requestOAuthPermission() {
        Log.i(TAG, "requestOAuthPermission called");
        FitnessOptions fitnessOptions = getFitnessSignInOptions();
        GoogleSignIn.requestPermissions(
                this,
                REQUEST_OAUTH_REQUEST_CODE,
                GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this),
                fitnessOptions);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // This ensures that if the user denies the permissions then uses Settings to re-enable
        // them, the app will start working.
        findFitnessDataSourcesWrapper();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onActivityResult called");
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_OAUTH_REQUEST_CODE) {
                findFitnessDataSources();
            }
        }
    }
    // [END auth_oncreate_setup]

    /** Finds available data sources and attempts to register on a specific {@link DataType}. */
    private void findFitnessDataSources() {
        Log.i(TAG, "findFitnessDataSources called");
        // [START find_data_sources]
        // Note: Fitness.SensorsApi.findDataSources() requires the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission.
        Fitness.getSensorsClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this))
                .findDataSources(
                        new DataSourcesRequest.Builder()
                                .setDataTypes(DataType.TYPE_HEART_RATE_BPM)
                                .setDataSourceTypes(DataSource.TYPE_RAW)
                                .build())
                .addOnSuccessListener(
                        new OnSuccessListener<List<DataSource>>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(List<DataSource> dataSources) {
                                Log.i(TAG, "Listener Success");
                                Log.i(TAG, "DataSources: " + dataSources.size());
                                for (DataSource dataSource : dataSources) {
                                    Log.i(TAG, "Data source found: " + dataSource.toString());
                                    Log.i(TAG, "Data Source type: " + dataSource.getDataType().getName());

                                    // Let's register a listener to receive Activity data!
                                    if (dataSource.getDataType().equals(DataType.TYPE_HEART_RATE_BPM)
                                            && mListener == null) {
                                        Log.i(TAG, "Data source for HEART RATE found!  Registering.");
                                        registerFitnessDataListener(dataSource);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        })
                .addOnFailureListener(
                        new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                Log.e(TAG, "failed", e);
                            }
                        });
        // [END find_data_sources]
    }

    /**
     * Registers a listener with the Sensors API for the provided {@link DataSource} and {@link
     * DataType} combo.
     */
    private void registerFitnessDataListener(DataSource dataSource) {
        Log.i(TAG, "registerFitnessDataListener called");
        // [START register_data_listener]
        mListener =
                new OnDataPointListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataPoint(DataPoint dataPoint) {
                        for (final Field field : dataPoint.getDataType().getFields()) {
                            final Value val = dataPoint.getValue(field);

                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    hR.setText(val.toString());
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                };

        Fitness.getSensorsClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this))
                .add(
                        new SensorRequest.Builder()
                                .setDataSource(dataSource) // Optional but recommended for custom data sets.
                                .setDataType(DataType.TYPE_HEART_RATE_BPM) // Can't be omitted.
                                .setSamplingRate(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                                .build(),
                        mListener)
                .addOnCompleteListener(
                        new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    Log.i(TAG, "Listener registered!");
                                } else {
                                    Log.e(TAG, "Listener not registered.", task.getException());
                                }
                            }
                        });
        // [END register_data_listener]
    }

    /** Unregisters the listener with the Sensors API. */
    private void unregisterFitnessDataListener() {
        Log.i(TAG, "unRegisterFitnessDataListener called");
        if (mListener == null) {
            // This code only activates one listener at a time.  If there's no listener, there's
            // nothing to unregister.
            return;
        }

        // [START unregister_data_listener]
        // Waiting isn't actually necessary as the unregister call will complete regardless,
        // even if called from within onStop, but a callback can still be added in order to
        // inspect the results.
        Fitness.getSensorsClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this))
                .remove(mListener)
                .addOnCompleteListener(
                        new OnCompleteListener<Boolean>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Boolean> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful() && task.getResult()) {
                                    Log.i(TAG, "Listener was removed!");
                                } else {
                                    Log.i(TAG, "Listener was not removed.");
                                }
                            }
                        });
        // [END unregister_data_listener]
    }


    /** Initializes a custom log class that outputs both to in-app targets and logcat. */

    /** Returns the current state of the permissions needed. */
    private boolean hasRuntimePermissions() {
        Log.i(TAG, "hasRuntimePermissions called");
        int permissionState =
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.BODY_SENSORS);
        return permissionState == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }

    private void requestRuntimePermissions() {
        boolean shouldProvideRationale =
                ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
                        this, Manifest.permission.BODY_SENSORS);

        if (shouldProvideRationale) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Displaying permission rationale to provide additional context.");

        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "Requesting permission");
            // Request permission. It's possible this can be auto answered if device policy
            // sets the permission in a given state or the user denied the permission
            // previously and checked "Never ask again".
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    Test_Page.this,
                    new String[] {Manifest.permission.BODY_SENSORS},
                    REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }

    /** Callback received when a permissions request has been completed. */
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(
            int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onRequestPermissionResult called");
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (grantResults.length <= 0) {
                // If user interaction was interrupted, the permission request is cancelled and you
                // receive empty arrays.
                Log.i(TAG, "User interaction was cancelled.");
            } else if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Permission was granted.
                findFitnessDataSourcesWrapper();
            } else {
                // Permission denied.
                Log.i(TAG, "Permission denied");

            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Right, sorry I will keep that in mind.

Comment: Hey were you able to figure this out?